# How to fix two label overlap each other

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I wrote it by `.html.erb` and `bootstrap`(Rails)

```
<span class="label label-primary">
    <% book.genres.each do |genres| %> 
    <%= genres.name %>
    <% end %>
</span>
```

The result is like this

[image]

But actually, I want it to be looked like

[image]

Comment: Move the span inside your foreach loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the `span` tag in the each loop.

```
<% book.genres.each do |genres| %> 
  <span class="label label-primary">
    <%= genres.name %>
  </span>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. In genera, how to add white space between two object ?  Use CSS?

Comment: If you only need one whitespace char, then you can just leave a whitespace char in HTML. If you need more use `&nbsp;`, which is a reserved whitespace char. Or you can always use Css to place elements wherever you like.

Comment: Thanks. I will use `&nbsp`.